# HTTP server HandleFunc loop on timeout?

Tags: http, go, server, timeout

I am working on a Go app that has a web server. I was trying to add timeouts and encountered an issue. Here's a sample code I made to reproduce it because posting the actual code would be impossible:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

var layout *template.Template

func main() {
    router := http.NewServeMux()
    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:         ":8888",
        Handler:      router,
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }

    router.HandleFunc("/", home)

    var err error
    layout, err = template.ParseFiles("./layout.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error1: %+v\n", err)
    }

    server.ListenAndServe()
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("responding")
    err := layout.Execute(w, template.HTML(`World`))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error2: %+v\n", err)
    }
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
}
```

**layout.html:** `Hello {{.}}!`

When I run it and visit 127.0.0.1:8888, the browser stays loading, and the `home()` which is triggering the timeout, starts over again and it does it 10 times before it stops and the browser shows a connection reset error.

I was expecting that after a timeout, the func would end immediately, the connection be closed and the browser stop loading and show an error.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "after a timeout" where? What are you expecting would cause the handler to "end imediately"? Nothing in Go has the power to force a running goroutine to stop from outside the goroutine.

Comment: I guess the WriteTimeout is the one being trigger, since without the sleep it works. You are right, is not what I am expecting but what I would like to achieve.

Comment: Nothing is going to stop the handler from outside. It's just a function, it stops when it returns.

Comment: If you would reach the write timeout Execute would return an error. There's no guesswork here. It is highly unlikely that you will ever get this timeout with a normal browser on localhost. time.Sleep is uninterruptible and not a good stand-in for real code, so we can't really make relevant suggestions here.

Comment: But why when running the server and visiting with a browser, I get ten println('responding') on the console and and then the browser shows a connection reset error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

immediately response use goroutines and context timeout

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

var layout *template.Template
var WriteTimeout = 1 * time.Second

func main() {
    router := http.NewServeMux()
    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:         ":8889",
        Handler:      router,
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: WriteTimeout + 10*time.Millisecond, //10ms Redundant time
        IdleTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }
    router.HandleFunc("/", home)
    server.ListenAndServe()
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("responding\n")
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), WriteTimeout)
    worker, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    var buffer string
    go func() {
        // do something
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        buffer = "ready all response\n"
        //do another
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        cancel()
        fmt.Printf("worker finish\n")
    }()
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        //add more friendly tips
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    case <-worker.Done():
        w.Write([]byte(buffer))
        fmt.Printf("writed\n")
        return
    }
}
```